# Cloned element not appearing at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be a very simple problem. I have an input and a button. My target is, when I click that button, a clone of that input element will appear. What I can't fix is, when I click the button, the cloned element appears only after the original element, but it should appear right at the bottom of all the cloned elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //addition buttons handler
    $(".btn-add").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var operation = id.split('-')[0].replace(/(?:^)\w/g, function (match) {
            return match.toUpperCase();
        });

        //$("#" + operation).first().clone().val("").insertAfter("#" + operation + ":last");
        //$("#" + operation + ":last").after($("#" + operation).first().clone().val(""));
        $("#" + operation).last().after($("#" + operation).first().clone().val(""));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="BccList" name="BccList" type="text" value="">
<button type="button" id="bccList-add" class="btn btn-primary btn-add">+</button>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: For next time, please make your runnable example **here**, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), rather than off-site. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use `class` rather than `id` for this.

### Details

`id` values **must** be unique on the page. When you break that rule, browsers are free to do whatever they want with the subsequent elements. The consensus seems to be that they leave the `id` on subsequent elements using it, but don't rely on that.

If they do (leave the `id` on subsequent elements), `$("#the-id")` returns a jQuery object wrapping **only the first one**:

```js
console.log($("#the-id").length); // 1
```

```html
<div id="the-id"></div>
<div id="the-id"></div>
<div id="the-id"></div>
<div id="the-id"></div>
<div id="the-id"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(But don't rely on that, either, because it's not true with more complex selectors.)